# Allowing another developer to deploy azure functions on my Azure subscription without my password?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm looking to build some Azure functions in the Azure Functions App Platform as a service. I have a developer who will help me.  Can I share the apps publishing profile with him without exposing my password or admin rights to my subscription?  Can he deploy into my app without having his own Azure subscription?  I suspect no, but need to know for sure.

Personally I think Microsoft would really grow their new cloud platforms significantly if they offered free developer licenses allowing those licenses to only run very limited IO and Volume for testing, say No private domains, 2 concurrent users, 5mb of data and 30 hits per day.  I know $150/month does not sound like much, but developers in other parts of the world it's a cost they can't seem to maintain.

Comment: You do not have to spend a minimum of $150 to gain access to azure. You can use the [free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/) or pay-per-use or use the [free tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/is-is/pricing/details/app-service/) so I think your understanding of azure pricing is incorrect. If you use the [consumption plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) you got a lot of free function time as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way for you to accomplish what you're asking about is to add the developer as a "Contributor" for a resource group in your Azure subscription.  This is done using the Access Control (IAM) blade for the Resource Group in the Azure Portal.  Information on role based access in Azure can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

As far as free access is concerned, there are definitely a lot of ways to avoid $150 per month in costs.  I have $150/month in Azure credit that comes with my MSDN subscription.  I usually choose free-tier resources when experimenting and if I need to use higher tier resources for something that I am trying to learn, I clean it up after I am done.  Using this approach, I rarely use more than $10 of my $150 allotment and am working with resources several times a week.  I'd recommend having them sign up for the free trial, setting up spending limits on the account, and using free-tier services.

Comment: I just double-checked my billing status.  For the billing period ending tomorrow, my projected total for the month will be $4.92

Comment: Kyle....Great answer! A few comments: 1) I would not recommend assigning a contributor role at resource group level; rather assign that role at a resource level. Doing it at resource group level would enable that user to deploy additional resources in that resource group. 2) Even better approach would be to create a custom role with only the permissions required to deploy the application. 3) Recently Microsoft sweetened the deal with 1 year of free Azure access (with some caveats though :)). More information on 1 free year can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?cdn=disable.